# Android Java - how to clear repeat drawings?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have this code where I draw on a canvas then convert to a bitmap.

```
predictBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //if image is empty then let the user know to upload one
                if(img == null){
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Upload an image first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } // otherwise run the custom tensorflow lite model


                else {
                    imageBox.destroyDrawingCache();
                    img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 281, 324, true);
                    try {

                        Android model = Android.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        // Creates inputs for reference.
                        TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(img);

                        // Runs model inference and gets result.
                        Android.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
                        Android.DetectionResult detectionResult = outputs.getDetectionResultList().get(0);

                        // Gets result from DetectionResult.
                        float score = detectionResult.getScoreAsFloat();
                        RectF location = detectionResult.getLocationAsRectF();
                        String category = detectionResult.getCategoryAsString();
                        //Create a new canvas to draw on
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
                        //draw on the canvas with the given location from the model
                        drawBoundingBox(canvas, location);
                        // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                        model.close();
                        // here we will print out the results of the object to text views based on the image that is inputted by the user
                        // we print out object type, accuracy score and location of object on the image

                        objecttv.setText(category);
                        scoretv.setText(Float.toString(score));
                        textBox.setText(newText);
                        imageBox.setImageBitmap(img);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //print out an error to the user and restart the activity.
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "An error happened " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        sameActivity();
                    }
                }// end of else
            }

        }
```

My code for drawBoundingBox

```
void drawBoundingBox(Canvas canvas, RectF location) {
        //calling invalidate() here gives me a cannot find symbol
        
        Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
        boxPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        boxPaint.setAlpha(200);
        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(location, boxPaint);
    }
```

Everytime I run the predict button it draws a new rectangle location but keeps the old location .

I've tried the following

```
imageBox.setImageDrawable(null);

imageBox.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Here is how the image looks each time.
[image: Image of object]

None of these clear my drawings , what else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new instance of imageBox instead of destroying it? Like imageBox = new ...

Comment: Hmm , no I haven't but I will try and let you know how that works out.

Comment: nope , still keeps the drawing

Comment: Any other ideas ? @AbishekStephen

Comment: You can try reloading the image again in that case.

Comment: reload the image where?